# Presto-Yarn Deployment using Manual slider

Tags: presto

I wanted to setup presto-yarn deployment using Manual Slider . so for this , i have built the presto-yarn package using maven and downloaded slideRunner as well and started executing the slider.When i am executing the below command getting the following error

command: bin/slider package --install --name PRESTO --package ../presto-yarn-package-*.zip

Error : Exception: [Errorno 2] No such file or directory.

All the files & directories are in place in the exact location including presto-yarn-package-*.zip binaries files & json files as well.

can any one assist me on this please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there maybe a stacktrace? Does it say anything about which file or directory is missing?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that conf/slider-env.sh and conf/slider-client.xml do not have any invalid paths.

Edit: Especially if you have set java_home/hadoop_conf in slider.env.sh - make sure it is a path which exists.